# global content loaded event listener

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I need an event listener which is global so when every content is loaded a function fires up and function places this content. I've tried

```
stage.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(evt:Event){placeem(evt, "stgW","stgH")});
```

but that's not right, gives me errors

Comment: Please do not use nameless function it will only hurt you in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such function is available in Flash. You need to control yourself the loading of your assets and fire up the function when they are all done. A loading queue such as this one might help:

http://blog.hydrotik.com/2007/10/29/queueloader-as3-rev-7-garbage-collection-soundmanager/